# Is it better to default to using OR or AND logic when it comes to database search?

Tags: mysql, search

Let's say I have a database containing student info, and I have the following fields:

1) Age group
2) Course name
3) Country of origin

If I were to build a search function, would it be better to assume that the user wants to search for students that matches:

Age group OR Course name OR Country of origin?

Or should I assume that users want to search for students that fulfil ALL criteria (i.e. AND logic)?

What's the best practice? I assume people mean OR most of the time, as that gives the most results.

What do you think?

Thanks very much for the feedback!!

Comment: It is better to force the user to make their choice explicit in the UI.

Comment: You'd probably want to ask your user group. chaining OR like that may result is a lot of what appear to be irrelevant matches. You could also include a checkbox for the criteria so they can choose what fields to search.

Comment: most people think OR unless it is wrapped in quotes then they think and.  Think google if you search for Ben Franklin, you may get results for Ben, or Franklin.  but if you search for "Ben Franklin" you get results that contain in order "BEN Franklin"

Comment: what would you expect if you type "spanish" for Course name and "Texas" for country? I would expect to get all spanish course from Texas for all age groups. Would it make sense for any user to get all spanish courses combined with all courses from Texas?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a big concern, give people the option. Otherwise, it depends on how it's commonly used. I'd expect to see AND so I can produce the most restrictive output and not have to sift through the stuff I don't want -- but I don't know what your user base is like; you should ask them.

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent candidate for User Focus Groups.  If you are building a site (as opposed to a software product or internal company application) where you do not have access to organizing focus groups, you could try and solicit feedback from your users in the form of surveys or a contact form.

Answer (score 0):

You could always create a fulltextindex against all those fields then do a search against the index.

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX giveitaname ON mytable (agefield, coursename, country);
```

Then query the index like this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE MATCH(agefield, coursename, country) against ('%search_variable_here%')
```

Now your search will work with partial words, mismatched orders and potentially be much more relevant and yield less zero-result results.

In the meantime, I personally wouldn't worry too much about the load between OR or AND, especially if you have your indexes set up properly.  You should make the choice based on the data set you are working with and what is most intuitive and relevant for your user base.